# Floating point comparison in MIPS

Tags: mips, mips32

I am trying to print the max of two floating point numbers, and then the max of two double percision floating point numbers. I keep getting this output:

The larger number is 1.10000002
The larger number is 5.2676887711382507e-315

I should be getting:

The larger number is 1.10000000
The larger number is 1.10000000

```
# maxFloat.s
         .data
msg:     .asciiz "The larger number is "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
num1:    .float 1.00000001
num2:    .float 1.0
num3:    .double 1.00000001
num4:    .double 1.0


         .text
         .globl main
main:   
        
        la $a0, num1        # storing num1's address
        la $a2, num2        # storing num1's address
        jal maxFloat        # jumps to maxFloat function

        li $v0, 4           # syscall 4 (print msg)
        la $a0, msg         # argument: string
        syscall             # print the string

        li $v0, 2           # syscall 4 (print float)
                            # argument: $f12 (float)
        syscall             # print the string

        li $v0, 4           # syscall 4 (print new line)
        la $a0, newline     # argument: string
        syscall             # print the string
        
        # Now do the same thing for doubles #

        la $a0, num3        # storing num1's address
        la $a2, num4        # storing num1's address
        jal maxDouble       # jumps to maxFloat function

        li $v0, 4           # syscall 4 (print msg)
        la $a0, msg         # argument: string
        syscall             # print the string

        li $v0, 3           # syscall 2 (print double)
                            # argument: $f12 (double)
        syscall             # print the string

        li $v0, 4           # syscall 4 (print new line)
        la $a0, newline     # argument: string
        syscall             # print the string

        li $v0, 10          # syscall 10 (exit)
        syscall

maxFloat:
        
        l.s $f0, ($a0)       # load num1
        l.s $f2, ($a2)       # load num2

        mov.s $f12, $f2      # default to retuning num2
        c.lt.s $f0, $f2      #if num1 is less than num2 then do nothing
        bc1t skipF             
        mov.s $f12, $f0      #if num1 is greater then return num1

skipF:
        jr $ra               # retrun to caller

maxDouble:
        
        l.d $f0, ($a0)       # load num3
        l.d $f2, ($a2)       # load num4

        mov.d $f12, $f2      # default to retuning num2
        c.lt.d $f0, $f2      #if num1 is less than num2 then do nothing
        bc1t skipD              
        mov.d $f12, $f0      #if num1 is greater then return num1

skipD:
        jr $ra               # retrun to caller
```

I tried to use a varitety of MIPS comamnds but cannot get it to print the right number. Also when I input 1.00000001 as the largest number 1.00000000 comes out.

Comment: The floating point return value is supposed to be in `$f0`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_iQTl9lbQE 

This video is what I was going by, also that turns my output into this:

The larger number is 0.00000000
The larger number is 0

Comment: Ok, it is fine to create/use your own or a non-standard calling convention.

Comment: However, what doesn't work is using `lwc1` with `xxx.d`.  `lwc1` loads single float and `xxx.d` uses double float.  There'll be no error for mixing the two, it just won't work.  For `maxDouble`, either load double constants from memory or convert from single to double before using some `xxx.d` operations.